# If the liquid internal parts of the Earth solidify, what will be the consequences?

Tags: magnetic-fields, earth, rotation

Will the Earth's radius just decrease, the daytime decrease, and the magnetic field seize to exist?

Comment: I think you may want to ask on a geology forum. You will probably get better answers there.

Comment: Maybe try [EarthScience.SE]?